# How to use ANT-433-SP antenna?

Tags: antenna

Could someone please explain to me how to use this antenna?
http://www.linxtechnologies.com/resources/data-guides/ant-433-sp.pdf

The picture on the last page called "Recommended Mounting" is really confusing me. The picture appears to illustrate the antenna mounted in the same plane as the PCB, hanging off the edge. Yet the connection itself would suggest that the antenna is actually standing on the PCB, in a perpendicular arrangement... So, which one is it?

Next, it refers to something it calls "PCB Pads". Is this some sort of standard part, or is it implying that these will be provided with the antenna?

Next, it shows a "Vias to ground plane". My understanding of vias is basically a through hole that connects two layers on a PCB together. If that is right, I really don't understand what it means in this context. What exactly am I supposed to connect to the ground plane? Is it suggesting that all the "dips" are connected to nothing, while all the flat parts are connected to ground with a vias?

Would you say that it will be possible for me to mount this antenna with just a soldering iron, or would I need some other equipment?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think the "Recommended Mounting" is suggesting any PCB edges. The gray area that ends by the pads is a ground plane on the bottom of the PCB.

Comment: @W5VO: So the antenna is standing on the board upright then? The flat parts are viased to ground, but what are all those notches connected to (the first one is RF signal, but what about the others)?

Comment: No - the antenna is laying flat on the PCB. The image is a top-down view, as if you were looking at it on your PCB design software. Pin 1 is RF in, and all the other pins are connected to ground.

Comment: @W5VO: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. I have never made a PCB yet, so I don't yet know how PCB software looks. So the antenna is lying flat on the PCB, but it is not directly above the ground plane - it just aligns its edge with it, right? Could you clarify one more thing for me? How do I make the electrical connection to those pads, now that they are standing up perpendicularly from the board? Is there a technique for that?

Answer (score 1):

It is surface mounted on the top of a PCB.  The PCB should have pads as shown (they are just squares of exposed conductor in the PCB pattern). The supply line should be a [microstrip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstrip) of 50 ohms impedance. And the pads connected to ground need vias since the ground plane is on the other side of the board.

It is meant to be mounted flat on the PCB, with castellations (plated half-holes) along the edge.  But I reckon you could mount it vertically and it would work OK, but weak mechanically.

Comment: But if I mount the antenna flat on the PCB (i.e. lying down on its wide side), the castellations and the ground pads will be perpendicular to the PCB. How do I make the electrical connection to the pads?

Comment: Also, is microstrip a separate part I have to purchase, or is it just a trace on the PCB?

Comment: Have you tried Googling for microstrip?

Comment: I did. It describes a conductive strip separated from a ground plane by a dielectric layer. That sounds like a trace etched on a double-sided PCB, which is why I am confused about it.

Comment: yes, the datasheet is only showing a PCB design.

Comment: How would I make a PCB trace that is exactly 50 ohms? I am assuming that they are not talking about DC resistance - it's probably impedance, right? Does "50-ohm" tell me something about the type of double-sided PCB I should be using?

Comment: 50 ohm impedance, yes.  The impedance is dependent on the PCB geometry.  I can't explain all of RF engineering in this comment thread, so I suggest you look in your local library for the "ARRL handbook" to learn the basics.

Comment: Thank you for the book reference. I'll be sure to check it out.